# How to use orbit-db visualization in dapp created using Embark Framework?

Tags: ipfs, embark

This is the contract code:-

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract SimpleStorage {
     string public storedData;
     function set(string x) {
                  storedData = x;
     }
     function get() constant returns (string x) {
                 return storedData;
     }
 }
```

Index.html code

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>Embark - SimpleStorage Demo</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
     <script src="web3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="ipfs.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body class="container">
       <h3>Embark - SimpleStorage Demo</h3>
    <h3> 1. Set the string in the blockchain</h3>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
          <input type="text" class="text form-control">
          <button class="set btn btn-primary">Set String</button>
   </div>
   <h3> 2. Get the current value</h3>
   <div class="form-group">
        <div>
              current value is <span class="value"></span>
       </div>
       <button class="get btn btn-primary">Get String</button>
  </div>
  <h3>File Uploading</h3>
        <h3> 1. Set the file in the blockchain</h3>
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
             <input type="file">
             <button class="setfile btn btn-primary">Set File</button>
        </div>
        <h3> 2. Get the current value</h3>
             <div class="form-group">
                  <div>
                    current value is <span class="valuefile"></span>
                  </div>
                  <button class="getfile btn btn-primary">Get File</button>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js file

```
 EmbarkJS.Messages.setProvider('orbit',{server: 'localhost', port: '5001'});
 $(document).ready(function() {
           $("button.set").click(function() {
                    var value = $("input.text").val();
                    EmbarkJS.Storage.saveText(value).then(function(hash) {
                    SimpleStorage.set(hash);
                    });
           });
         $("button.get").click(function() {
                   SimpleStorage.get().then(function(hash) {
                   EmbarkJS.Storage.get(hash).then(function(content) {
                           $(".value").html(content);
                   });
                   });
        });

        $("button.setfile").click(function() {
                            var input = $("input[type=file]");
                     console.log(input);                                    

                   EmbarkJS.Storage.uploadFile(input).then(function(hash) {
                             SimpleStorage.set(hash);
                              console.log(hash);
                   });
           });
           $("button.getfile").click(function() {
                   SimpleStorage.get().then(function(hash) {
                             console.log("get");
                              console.log(hash);
                             EmbarkJS.Storage.getUrl(hash);
                            $(".valuefile").html("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/"+hash);
                              console.log("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/"+hash);

                            });
                    });
        });
```

I have created a dapp which saves the hash of text and file in orbit-db and retrieves it back.
I have used orbit-db for storing data.How can i visualize the data stored in orbit-db?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up the provider for Messages instead of Storage. Note that the Orbit provider being used in Messages is intended for pub-sub messages just like whisper and not for database storage.

Comment: @ iurimatias i have used ipfs as database storage.How can we visualize the hash stored in ipfs?

Comment: Please see the docs https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework#embarkjs---storage

Comment: ```EmbarkJS.Storage.get(hash).then(function(content) {});``` and/or ```EmbarkJS.Storage.getUrl(hash);```

Comment: @criss you are welcome to join us at http://gitter.im/iurimatias/embark-framework for any help you might need